# perl, tk how to save this image into a file?

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I am learning tk and trying to debug my script. I'm not sure what I am missing to get my image saved into a file. Thanks for any help

```
#!/tool/pandora64/bin/perl5.8.8.a

use Tk;

my ( $size, $step ) = ( 200, 10 );

# Create MainWindow and configure:
my $mw = MainWindow->new;
$mw->configure( -width=>$size, -height=>$size );
$mw->resizable( 0, 0 ); # not resizable in any direction

# Create and configure the canvas:
my $canvas = $mw->Canvas( -cursor=>"crosshair", -background=>"white",
              -width=>$size, -height=>$size )->pack;

# Place objects on canvas:
$canvas->createRectangle( $step, $step, $size-$step, $size-$step, -fill=>"red" );

for( my $i=$step; $i<$size-$step; $i+=$step ) {
  my $val = 255*$i/$size;
  my $color = sprintf( "#%02x%02x%02x", $val, $val, $val );
  $canvas->createRectangle( $i, $i, $i+$step, $i+$step, -fill=>$color );
}

$canvas->postscript( -file=>"file_name.ps" );

`convert file_name.ps file_name.jpeg`; # I can move this outside out of the script

exit 0;
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code above?  Are there any error messages?  Is there unexpected output?

Comment: it creates the files file_Name.ps and file_name.jpeg, when i view the file_name.jpeg, it shows nothing ...

Comment: That convert in backticks is trying to spaw a new process, and you're not checking if that succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the "convert" (in backticks) failed for some reason (e.g. not in path). You need to check if that succeeded. There are safer ways to spawn a subprocess in perl, e.g. using a "system" call.

---

Based on Gordon's comment below, i wish to change my answer:

http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M60

> Note: by default Postscript is only generated for information that appears in the canvas's window on the screen. If the canvas is freshly created it may still have its initial size of 1x1 pixel so nothing will appear in the Postscript. To get around this problem either invoke the "update" command to wait for the canvas window to reach its final size, or else use the -width and -height options to specify the area of the canvas to print. The option-value argument pairs provide additional information to control the generation of Postscript.

Answer (score 0):

When the canvas generates postscript, it tries to do so for the visible portion of the screen by default; this information is set on the generated postscript file as a bounding box declaration. If you've never mapped the canvas (with pack or grid followed by handling events for a while) the area it sets as the bounding box will be bogus; the data will be there in the file, but when rendered to the screen or to an image only a tiny part of it will actually be used.

The fix for this (given your workflow above) is to explicitly state the bounding box.

```
$canvas->postscript( -file=>"file_name.ps", -width=>$size, -height=>$size );
```

Once you've done that, you don't actually need to specify anything about the main window (other than that it logically exists). You can also drop the specification of the cursor for the canvas; that won't be used during PS generation.